# tab indent in sublime text2

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation

my setting:

```
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

but it doesn't work. when I press tab key, it remains two characters indent.

why?
tks!

Comment: Are you setting this in your user preferences file?  If so, is it surrounded by curly braces?

Comment: no. my user setting: '{
 "font_size": 18.0,
 "ignored_packages":
 [
 ]
}'

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "detect_indentation": false